# How to display second form by clicking first lightning component form?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Here I'm displaying two forms in single page 1.customer login form and 2.customer details form.

By using phonenumber I can able to get data from salesforce by clicking a button and diplaing in customer details form.

Requirement is  :

I don't want to display two forms in same page.How can I display login form first after clicking a button it display customer details form.

[image]

### Component :

```
<aura:component controller="RPAProcess" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
aura:attribute name="RPABot" type="RPABot__c" default="{'sobjectType':'RPABot__c'}" />
  aura:attribute name="PhoneNumber" type="String" default="" />

   div class="slds-page-header">
        div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            div class="slds-text-heading_large">
                div class="slds-m-top_xx-large">
                    <b>  Customer Login Form </b>
                /div>
            /div>
        /div>
   /div>  
   div class="slds-size_3-of-12"> 
        lightning:input label="Phone Number" name="phonenumber" value="{!v.PhoneNumber}" required = "true"/>
        br/>  
        lightning:button variant="brand" label="Get Data" onclick="{!c.getData}" />       
  </div>  


    div class="slds-m-top_xx-large">
           <b>Cutomer Details </b>
    /div>

    div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
        lightning:input label="CustomerID" name="rpaId" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_ID__c}" /> 
       <br/>    
        lightning:input label="Customer Name" name="customername" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_Name__c}" />
        <br/>      
        lightning:input label="Company" name="dob" value="{!v.RPABot.Company__c}" />
        <br/>       >
    </div> 
/aura:component>
```

### component.js

```
({
    getData : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getDetails");  

            action.setParams({  
            phonenumber : component.get("v.PhoneNumber")               
        });                  
          action.setCallback(this, function(response){                              
          component.set("v.RPABot",response.getReturnValue());      
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `Customer_Name__c` in default of attribute `RPABot`.
2. Put 1st form and 2nd form in `aura:if`, such that 1st form is shown when `Customer_Name__c` is empty. When you get back the data `Customer_Name__c` is not empty and so 1st form is removed and 2nd form is rendered.

Below is the code of **.cmp**:

```
<aura:component controller="RPAProcess" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="RPABot" type="RPABot__c" default="{'sobjectType':'RPABot__c','Customer_Name__c':''}" />
    <aura:attribute name="PhoneNumber" type="String" default="" />


    <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.RPABot.Customer_Name__c)}">
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <div class="slds-text-heading_large">
                    <div class="slds-m-top_xx-large">
                        <b> Customer Login Form </b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
            <lightning:input label="Phone Number" name="phonenumber" value="{!v.PhoneNumber}" required="true" />
            <br />
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Get Data" onclick="{!c.getData}" />
        </div>
    </aura:if>


    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.RPABot.Customer_Name__c))}">
        <div class="slds-m-top_xx-large">
            <b>Cutomer Details </b>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
            <lightning:input label="CustomerID" name="rpaId" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_ID__c}" />
            <br />
            <lightning:input label="Customer Name" name="customername" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_Name__c}" />
            <br />
            <lightning:input label="Company" name="dob" value="{!v.RPABot.Company__c}" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thats great.It works perfectly.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without going in much of the code detail, you can use [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation) to decide at run time which form to display.

Now when user completes form1, fire a [component event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component.htm) to the parent component to convey form1 is completed and show form 2.

Code will be somewhat like:

Parent Component:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute type="Boolean" default="true" name="showForm1"/>
    <aura:handler name="completedForm1Event" event="c:compEvent"
                action="{!c.handleForm1Completion}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showForm1}">

        <c:form1 />

    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!NOT(v.showForm1)}">

        <c:form2 />

    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Parent JS:

```
handleForm1Completion(component){
    component.set("v.showForm1" , false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the info.Here my requirement is based on phone number I want to get the salesforce record details but I want to display details in other page by clicking "details" button in first page.How to achieve this please help me on this.

Comment: please check the image added at the top. after clicking the get data button i want to display details in other page.How to achieve this?

Comment: @Raghu I mentioned right, fire event from form1, capture it in parent, and make parent to display form2.

Comment: thanks i will try and let you know any issues